# Vertical space before section title with titlesec

Tags: spacing, sectioning, fontsize, titlesec

I was trying to eliminate the vertical space before and after the title of a section by using the `titlesec` package and the command `\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}`, but it works only in eliminating the vertical space after the section title. Before the section title there still is a portion of double space. I've searched the database and didn't find a solution.

Comment: Do you use the `setspace` package and `\doublespacing`? A a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be helpful.

Comment: No, I don't. I use Lyx 2.0.2 with default settings. In the preamble I have `\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\date{}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*0}{0pt}`

Comment: Now I clicked to see the complete source and `setspace` appears with `\onehalfspacing`. But the space before the section title is clearly bigger than the one after.

Comment: Check your PDF (or DVI) ouutput file -- perhaps the problem is limited to LyX's display.

Comment: I've checked it. The same problem in the PDF xetex output.

Comment: @lockstep: Add the tag LyX ;-)

Comment: Then it's definitely time for a minimal working example.

Comment: Ok. Here: `% Preview source code

\documentclass[12pt,english]{extarticle}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\date{}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*0}{0pt}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

Name:

\pagebreak{}

\bf 22. Discuss LOT. \rm
Intro

\section*{{\normalsize LOT}}

The LOT hypothesis

\section*{{\normalsize The Regress Argument}}

RA

\end{document} `

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I forgot to indent it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't switch to `\normalsize` inside the argument of `\section`; use `titlesec`s `\titleformat` macro instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*0}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{LOT}

The LOT hypothesis

\section*{The Regress Argument}

RA

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I just had to add `titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}` to my preamble and it solved the problem, although I couldn't edit the source code in LyX and the `\normalsize` setting is still there. But it works this way.